# Virtualbox Internet connection

Tags: virtual-machine, fedora

Hello everyone,

I am using Windows XP SP3 with Oracle VirtualBox installed in it. I am running Fedora 15 as a guest OS. Now my Internet Service Provider provides the internet connection on basis of MAC address locking which basically means that if the MAC address of my computer changes then I will not be able to connect to the internet. My query is that **how does virtual box connect to the internet from inside a guest OS?**
I have already seen the creation of another network in my computer ie. **Virtual Box Host Only Network**--**What is this ?** Again when I run *ipconfig* from the command prompt I get two different networks with two different MAC addresses. **Now how come Virtual Box connects under this connection called Virtual Box Host Only Network ie. connects under a different MAC address and yet my ISP does not allow connection under a different MAC address?** Does it map the MAC address of one network to the original MAC address or is it something else? Basically I want to know how all Virtual Box connects to the internet? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox's host-only networking is used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host.

A virtual network card is installed on the host machine and the virtual machine connects with that.  That virtual card then gets its data from the host machine's internet connected NIC.

In your case, based on the fact the ISP is checking MACs, bridged networking would not work for you, however NAT would.

FYI, all modern home routers have MAC address cloning, so you could put one behind your modem and give it your PCs MAC and then you would be able to connect multiple physical PCs.  You would also be able to used bridged networking on your VMs.

Check out this [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes) on VirtualBox networking for a description of the different network types supported.